# Eigen map with array of 2 components to vector of 3

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a vector of `std::array<double, 2>` elements. I need to convert this to an `Eigen::Vector3d` to use a library and I want to know if there is anyway to use an Eigen::Map to interface with my vector. If my vector was an std::array<double, 3>` I could do something like

```
        std::array<double, 3> dx;
        Eigen::Map<const Eigen::VectorXd> dx_eig(&dx_[0][0], 3 * dx.size());
```

but my vector is made of `std::array<double, 2>` and I can't use directly an Eigen::Map as far as I know.

I want something like this:

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 2>> x;
Eigen::Map<Eigen::Vector3d> x_eig(x, ???)
```

such that `x_eig` behaves like in the following example

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 2>> x;
Eigen::Vector3d x_eig(3*x.size());
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
{
    x_eig[3*i + 0] = x[i][0];
    x_eig[3*i + 1] = x[i][1];
    x_eig[3*i + 2] = 0;
}
```

The last snipper requires duplicating memory and copying. If its possible to use some kind of map, it would be possible to reduce memory consumption and maybe improve performance.

As far as I know, Eigen::Map allows to use an `Stride` class to provide some strides, but they basically size in bytes for next element in a row and size in bytes for next element in a column. No way to specify something much more complex like, read 2 consecutive double and then a 0.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre], i.e., how would you do manually what you need to do. I have no idea how you want to map from `std::vector<std::array<double,2>>` (`2*n` elements) to 3 elements. Also, in the snippet you provide there is no `dx_`, just a `dx`.

Comment: `Vector3d` holds exactly 3 elements. Do you want a `Matrix3Xd`perhaps? What operation do you do afterwards with that?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can convert to 3d as said below and pass the vector to `Eigen::Map`.

```
//YOUR ARRAY.
std::array<double,2> d2 = {1,2};

//CREATE A VECTOR.
std::vector<double> d3(std::begin(d2), std::end(d2);

//ADD THIRD ELEMENT.
d3.push_back(0);
```

Now pass it to `Eigen::Map`

Comment: Im currently using something like. Instead of creating a vector, I just create the Eigen::Vector3d. I was asking for a solution that doesn't imply using more memory and wasting time copying memory.

Comment: I think it is difficult to find a solution with out copying. As you know Arrays are fixed in size. Either you or the library should do copy operation to make it from 2 to 3 (as it is array). Another option is, if it is not a huge code base replace the arrays with vectors everywhere. Then you will have all the flexibilities.